# Does the iPad have a governor?

Tags: ipad, html

I loop through an ajax recordset and insert rows into an html5 database.
In Google Chrome, the program inserts 581 rows, whereas on the iPad, it only inserts between 20 and 80 rows.

I output the commands to the document body just to make sure they are being run, so I know there are 581 insert statements being run on the iPad, but then the table only has a handful.

Comment: Without code, it didn't happen ;-)

Comment: I ran it once in Chrome, and it produced 400 some odd rows instead of the normal 581.

Comment: I think it might be that navigating around on the screen interrupts the processing.  That because I'm scrolling down, it stops the insert commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you move the screen around while something is processing, it stops the processing.
Try displaying a countdown on the INSERT INTO callback, and you will see that it stops the countdown if you scroll the screen down.

Answer (score 0):

OK, here's how I do it.
I first drop the table, then when that's done, I create the table.
Then when that's done, I do my ajax call.
When that comes back, I loop through the recordset and insert into the html5 local database.

```
var DropTableiUsr = function() {
    var DropTableDeferred = new $.Deferred();
    var CreateTableDeferred = new $.Deferred();
    dbo.transaction(function(myTrans) {
        myTrans.executeSql(
            'drop table iUsr;'
            ,[]
            ,DropTableDeferred.resolve()
        );
    });
    DropTableDeferred.done(function() {
        dbo.transaction(function(myTrans) {
            myTrans.executeSql(
                'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS iUsr' 
                + '(UsrID Integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY'
                + ',UsrGradeDate Varchar(128)'
                + ');'
                ,[]
                ,CreateTableDeferred.resolve()
            );
        });
    });
    CreateTableDeferred.done(function() {
        var settings = {};
        settings.data = {};
        settings.data.method = 'View0';
        var myPromise = $(this).myAjax('com/Usr.cfc', settings); // 'this' normally points to the DOM element that is the context of what caused the Ajax call.
        myPromise.done(function(result) {
            if (result.RTN) {
                var qryUsr = result.qry.DATA;
                qryUsr.RecordCount = result.qry.ROWCOUNT;
                // qryUsr.ColumnList = result.qry.COLUMNS;
                for (var CurrentRow=0;CurrentRow < qryUsr.RecordCount;CurrentRow++) {
                    myFunction(CurrentRow);
                };
                function myFunction(CurrentRow) {
                    $('body').append('INSERT INTO iUsr(UsrID,UsrGradeDate) VALUES(' + qryUsr.USRID[CurrentRow] + ',' + qryUsr.USRGRADEDATE[CurrentRow] + ')<br>');
                    dbo.transaction(function(myTrans) {
                        myTrans.executeSql(
                            'INSERT INTO iUsr(UsrID,UsrGradeDate) VALUES(?,?)',
                            [
                                qryUsr.USRID[CurrentRow],
                                qryUsr.USRGRADEDATE[CurrentRow]
                            ]
                        )
                    });
                };
            } else {
                $('#msg').text(result.MSG);
            }
        });
        myPromise.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus,C ) {
            alert('PopulateiUsr: ' + C);
            $('.container').append(jqXHR.responseText);
        })
        $('body').append('iUsr<br>');
    });
};

$('#Reset').click(function() {
    DropTableiUsr();
});
```

Comment: Hi Pedro, you can use the 'edit' function on your question to include your code.

Comment: OK ChrstopheD, thanks.  Maybe I should use some sort of callback mechanism with my INSERT INTO commands.

Comment: I wonder if there's a way I can batch insert all 581 rows instead of issuing 581 INSERT INTOs.